# Show that the max of two submartingale is also a submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

Show that the maximum of two submartingales (relative to the same filtration) is a submartingale.

Answer (score 17):

By definition:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X_n,Y_n)|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\geq \mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\geq X_{n-1}
$$
similarly:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X_n,Y_n)|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\geq \mathbb{E}[Y_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\geq Y_{n-1}
$$
Hence:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X_n,Y_n)|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}]\geq  \max(X_{n-1},Y_{n-1})
$$